# Strange node.js error: TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on'

Tags: javascript, node.js, screen-scraping, node.js-connect

I'm trying to run a simple screen scraping app in node.js. The code is posted here:
https://github.com/anismiles/jsdom-based-screen-scraper
http://anismiles.wordpress.com/2010/11/29/node-js-and-jquery-to-scrape-websites/

The server starts up fine, but then when I run a query on it, I get the following error. Does anyone know why that is?

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on'
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/avishai/Downloads/anismiles-jsdom-based-screen-scraper-f0c79d3/searcher-server.js:9:10)
    at param (/Users/avishai/.node_libraries/.npm/connect/0.5.10/package/lib/connect/middleware/router.js:146:21)
    at param (/Users/avishai/.node_libraries/.npm/connect/0.5.10/package/lib/connect/middleware/router.js:157:15)
    at pass (/Users/avishai/.node_libraries/.npm/connect/0.5.10/package/lib/connect/middleware/router.js:162:10)
    at Object.router [as handle] (/Users/avishai/.node_libraries/.npm/connect/0.5.10/package/lib/connect/middleware/router.js:168:6)
    at next (/Users/avishai/.node_libraries/.npm/connect/0.5.10/package/lib/connect/index.js:218:15)
    at Server.handle (/Users/avishai/.node_libraries/.npm/connect/0.5.10/package/lib/connect/index.js:231:3)
    at Server.emit (events.js:45:17)
    at HTTPParser.onIncoming (http.js:1078:12)
    at HTTPParser.onHeadersComplete (http.js:87:31)
```

The function that appears to be throwing the error is:

```
function books(app){
    app.get('/:query', function(req, res, next) {

        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });

        var rediff = require('./searcher-rediff');
        rediff.on('on_book', function(item){
            res.write(item + "<br/>");
        });
        rediff.on('completed', function(){
            res.end();
        });
        rediff.search(escape(req.params.query));

    });
}
```

**UPDATE**

Now I noticed that on the first request, I get this:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word
    at Module._compile (module.js:369:25)
    at Object..js (module.js:380:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:306:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:272:10)
    at require (module.js:318:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/avishai/Downloads/anismiles-jsdom-based-screen-scraper-f0c79d3/searcher.js:2:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:380:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:306:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:272:10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fundamental reason behind this bug should be something to do with the `EventEmittter`. Allow me to explain,

1. `searcher.js` inherits from `EventEmitter`
   (Line-26) `Searcher.prototype = new process.EventEmitter`;
2. `searcher-rediff.js`, `searcher-flipkart.js` and `searcher-landmarkonthenet.js` extend from `searcher.js`, so they also inherit from `EventEmitter`.
3. ‘on’ method is actually defined in `EventEmitter`.

So, I think, for some reason, `searcher.js` is not able to inherit from `EventEmitter` and hence the method ‘on’ is missing.

Comment: I see... So how do I make it so that searcher.js _is_ able to inherit from EventEmitter?

Answer (score 3):

The only explanation that comes to mind is that the required module is not an EventEmmiter instance. Therefore, it does not have an 'on' method.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to setup a listener on a module instead of an EventEmitter.

`require('./searcher-rediff');` returns a Javascript module. I imagine there is actually an object in the `searcher-rediff` module that is the EventEmitter you are looking for.

Look through the `searcher-rediff.js` code to see where an EventEmitter is defined and exported, then you'll need to reference that.

In the end you'll probably end up with something like...

```
 var rediff = require('./searcher-rediff').searcher;
```